# PHP if ($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) causing site to crash with Error code: ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, github

To give some background I am working with a unmanaged VPS on Ubuntu 12.10.  I wanted to use it for a Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.5 server.  So this is my first time compiling both from source.  I was successful in getting them both to operate and serve html and PHP content, but I am having issues with my setup.

My current issue is this PHP code:

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) {
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
}
```

I am attempting to use this to get the real IP from my reverse proxy style CDN, but reguardless this code crashes the site with the errors below displayed in the browers, but when I test the code above on any other PHP host I have it does not cause any issue (wether it works or not is another question).

These are errors I receive from the code above from a PHP page working fine before the code snippet and fine with it commented out.

Chrome:

```
This webpage is not available
The webpage at http://domain.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error code: ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
```

Firefox:

```
Content Encoding Error
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.
```

IE:

```
This page can’t be displayed
•Make sure the web address http://domain.com is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.
```

Researching I have not found anyone who has solved this issue.  Some previous posts I found suggested compression related errors, but that dosen't seem correct in my case since the site works without that snippet of code.  I do not know if it could be related to my PHP configuration?  As it was my first time compiling from github I am unsure if I got everything correct.

Any suggestions to get this error fixed would be greatly appreciated.

Here is how I compiled PHP:

```
cd /usr/local/src/
git clone --branch PHP-5.5 https://github.com/php/php-src.git php55
cd /usr/local/src/php55
rm -rf configure
./buildconf --force

./configure \
--enable-opcache \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-dba \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-shmop \
--enable-sigchild \
--enable-soap \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-wddx \
--enable-zip \
--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs \
--with-bz2 \
--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/apache2/conf \
--with-curl \
--with-gd \
-–with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib \
--with-gettext \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-mysql-sock=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock \
--with-mysqli \
--with-openssl \
--with-pdo-mysql \
--with-pdo-pgsql \
--with-xmlrpc \
--with-zlib

make && \
make test && \
make install
```

Comment: general rule: other than _COOKIE and _SESSION, you should NOT be fiddling with values in the superglobals. they should be treated as read-only.

Comment: Marc, thanks, I took your advice and just tried the code: "var_dump($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);" and it causes the same error, so it seems that changing the superglobal variable is not my issue here.   I full page of php loading fine will stop loading everything and only show the error I referenced above after adding "var_dump($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);" so it must be a issue related to my configuration.

Comment: dumping out a simple variable causing a crash is VERY weird...

Comment: After testing, this error is given when any valid PHP code is added to the specific file before the final line of "$response->output();" which dynamically generates the page from modularized code.  So even echo "Hello World"; results in the error before "$response->output();" , but works fine directly after.   Why would that be?

Comment: no idea. you'd have to look at the bug lists for whatever framework/system `$response` is part of.